# React-Native Upload Image with Fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to send/upload image file to my back-end server with using fetch in react-native, but I cant achieve anything even I tried different examples. My backend is php/laravel. I use Image picker in react-native it works fine.

First I get image from library like this;

```
pick(){
        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);

            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            }
            else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            }
            else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
            }
            else {
                let source = { uri: response };

                // You can also display the image using data:
                // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

                this.uploadImage(response)
            }
        });
    }
```

console.log of selected image;

```
{height: 332, width: 443, type: null, fileName: "YnVocPlX7yKpxrUczoySYLkKhuChMhAaIzvHlezj2VZIgwVxND…SBaBiCCszMjVNAtyy1gWQbQl6AIF7ZQ=w443-h332-nc.jpeg", fileSize: 39718, …}
data: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAMCAgoKCgoKCgoKCg"
fileName: "YnVocPlX7yKpxrUczoySYLkKhuChMhAaIzvHlezj2VZIgwVxNDwwSTxrKpIW6OydrR5Ll-LzH5pzqDYCJA3l5JySBaBiCCszMjVNAtyy1gWQbQl6AIF7ZQ=w443-h332-nc.jpeg"
fileSize: 39718
height: 332
isVertical: true
originalRotation: 0
path: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/YnVocPlX7yKpxrUczoySYLkKhuChMhAaIzvHlezj2VZIgwVxNDwwSTxrKpIW6OydrR5Ll-LzH5pzqDYCJA3l5JySBaBiCCszMjVNAtyy1gWQbQl6AIF7ZQ=w443-h332-nc.jpeg"
type: null
uri: "content://media/external/images/media/22"
width: 443
__proto__: Object
```

Then I try to upload;

```
uploadImage(source){

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('name', 'testName'); // you can append anyone.
        data.append('photo', {
            uri: source.uri,
            type: 'image/jpeg', // or photo.type
            name: 'testPhotoName'
        });

        fetch('https://xxx/react_image', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body: data,
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

               console.log(responseJson);

            }).catch((error) => {
            //
        });
    }
```

and I get response and see it in console from my backend server;

```
{name: "testName", photo: {…}}
name: "testName"
photo: {}
__proto__: Object
```

and as you see the name is ok, same as I sent but the photo is empty object?? I dont know what I should do about it(In backend server I just send back the request as: return $request;).

Comment: Is your backend returning photo?

Comment: my back end returning the full request, as it arrived.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are providing image `URI`, I suggest trying with `base64`. You can convert `URI` to `base64` with following:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagestore#getbase64fortag

And here is working example which uses `XMLHttpRequest`, which might be an alternative for the `fetch` you are using:

```
ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(source.uri, (base64Data) => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            resolve();
        }
    };

    fd.append('file', base64Data);
    xhr.send(fd);
});
```

Just try it.

Comment: well I never used XML but ok i will try to apply it fast and tell you what I get..

Comment: Great. Please notice that I've edited this code block, as there was a small issue.

Comment: How I should get the response and console.log it? with XML?

Comment: It's already shown in my answer, see: `var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: Says: Cannot have a non-function arg after a function arg, and i dont get nothing from console.log(response)